# Robospice : CachedSpiceReques.getSpiceRequest not found

Tags: android, rest, robospice

I just tried to integrate the robospice framework https://github.com/octo-online/robospice into my android app. I am not using maven so i followed the steps suggested in this thread https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/issues/17 to run it in a "non maven" style
where i included the libs generated int the steps and included it in my android project:
robospice-1.3.2-SNAPSHOT.jar and so forth

Everything seemed to work just fine but it crashes after the REST call is sent, with the crash:

```
01-04 16:42:43.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2369): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
01-04 16:42:43.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2369): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com.octo.android.robospice.request.CachedSpiceRequest.getSpiceRequest
01-04 16:42:43.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2369):     at com.octo.android.robospice.SpringAndroidSpiceService.addRequest(SpringAndroidSpiceService.java:35)
01-04 16:42:43.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2369):     at com.octo.android.robospice.SpiceManager.run(SpiceManager.java:179)
01-04 16:42:43.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2369):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

so it seems to me i do not have the right framework file hence the CachedSpiceRequest.getSpiceRequest ist missing.

Does anybody know where this issue might come from? Maybe someone has a solution or knows which version of the framework works just fine since there is only a short tutorial at the github site which seems outdated.

i appreciate any help.

br Mike

*update*
this is my service:

```
public class TractiveJSONSpiceService extends JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService {
 /** Timeout when calling a web service (in ms). */
private static final int WEBSERVICES_TIMEOUT = 30000;

@Override
public RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = super.createRestTemplate();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    httpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout( WEBSERVICES_TIMEOUT );
    httpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout( WEBSERVICES_TIMEOUT );
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory( httpRequestFactory );

    return restTemplate;
}
```

the request is the same as in the tweet example:

```
public class TweetsRequest extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest< ListTweets > {

private String keyword;

public TweetsRequest( String keyword ) {
    super( ListTweets.class );
    this.keyword = keyword;
}

@Override
public ListTweets loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {

    // With Uri.Builder class we can build our url is a safe manner
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = Uri.parse( "http://search.twitter.com/search.json" ).buildUpon();
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter( "q", keyword );
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter( "rpp", "100" );
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter( "lang", "en" );

    String url = uriBuilder.build().toString();

    return getRestTemplate().getForObject( url, ListTweets.class );
}

/**
 * This method generates a unique cache key for this request. In this case our cache key depends just on the
 * keyword.
 * 
 * @return
 */
public String createCacheKey() {
    return "tweets." + keyword;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the SpringAndroidSpiceService, or any subclass of it, then you should use a SpringAndroidSpiceRequest. Those requests will receive the Spring Android rest template from the service when they are executed.

Comment: Thanx for your response but unfortunately i already use a subclass of the service (see updated post)

Comment: I updated the question, however, since this was just a prototyping project i also worked with : 
[DataDroid](http://www.datadroidlib.com/installation)
-> As the robospice was not working i tried it, and this worked without any pain, so thanks for your help, but i will stick to DataDroid for now. 

Hope it did not cost you too much time.

Comment: Hi Mike, that's fine really. If you had it somewhere on github, feel free to submit an issue on RoboSpice issues page on GitHub. But again, I guess everything is solved now.